Android 13: Query DNS details using adb shell?
Using adb shell and ifconfig I can query the network interfaces and assigned IPs. However, I do not see any DNS details. How can I find the DNS servers which Android is using?
private_dns_mode=off. My question is not about how to setup a private DNS server. My question is about the default DNS servers used by the device if private_dns_mode=off. How to find the IP addresses for these DNS servers?

Similar question (without answer) https://stackoverflow.com/q/65307621/150978

I hope there was a better way, but unfortunately you can't get it from ndc, settings, ip, etc.
Then, if you desperately need the DNSs you can use something like this (using AndroidViewClient/culebra.
You may need to adapt some things like the WiFi network name, but at least is something.
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient


def f(whc, p):
    if whc.text == "DNS":
        for ch in p.children:
            print(ch.text)
    
def traverse(wh, f, p):
    if wh:
        f(wh, p)
        for whc in wh.children:
            traverse(whc, f, wh)

subprocess.run(["adb", "shell", "am", "start", "-a", "android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS"])
helper = ViewClient.view_client_helper()
obj_ref = helper.until.find_object(body={'desc': 'AndroidWifi,Connected,Wifi signal full.,Open network'})
helper.ui_object2.click(oid=helper.ui_device.wait(oid=obj_ref.oid)["oid"])
helper.ui_device.wait_for_window_update()
helper.ui_device.swipe(segments=[(300, 1500), (300, 300)], segment_steps=50)
helper.ui_device.wait_for_window_update()
traverse(helper.ui_device.dump_window_hierarchy(), f, None)
helper.ui_device.press_back()
helper.ui_device.press_back()

that when runs it shows (for the emulator):
DNS
fec0::3
10.0.2.3

Update
The latest version (AndroidViewClient 24.1.0) introduces get_from_parent() and it's possible to remove the tree traversal as showed in this example: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/helper/get-wifi-dns

I was hoping I can get the DNS settings for the mobile network.

Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in setting on Android to directly view the DNS IP address used on a mobile network. This information is typically handled automatically by your carrier's network infrastructure.
